# How I can stop thread in RecyclerView ViewHolder when activity finished?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview, activity-finish

I make an activity with a `RecyclerView`;

In the `RecyclerView`, I made a song list with a seekbar and play button.

In seekbar, this moved with music current position using thread

But change activity, music is stop but error

I want when i change the activity, music is stop and not error

Please help me

```
//seekbar change listener
seekbar.setMax(music.getDuration());

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(fromUser)
            music.seekTo(progress);
    }
});

//music playing
public void button(View v){
if(music.isPlaying()){
    music.stop();
    try {
        music.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    music.seekTo(0);

    button.setText(R.string.start);
    seekbar.setProgress(0);
    }else{
    music.start();
    button.setText(R.string.stop);

    Thread();
}
}

//Thread
public void Thread(){
    Runnable task = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            while(music.isPlaying()){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                seekbar.setProgress(music.getCurrentPosition());
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: have you try to kill your methods in onStop() or onPause() method?

Comment: I tried but in case it is in recyclerview.viewholder so i can't use onStop() or onPause method

Answer (score 0):

The thread only can be kill in Activity or Fragment. Use this class to override your recyclerview click listener.

Create new java file and name it `RecyclerItemClickListener.java`

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

In your activity/fragment

```
yourRecyclerviewId.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(View view1, int position) {
           //view1 - is clicked view
           //position - position of the clicked list

           //put your method in here

       }
}));
```

Now, you can use OnPause() and OnStop() method to kill the thread or services